# How to make strpos case insensitive

Tags: php, strpos

How can I change the strpos to make it non case sensitive. The reason is if the `product->name` is *MadBike* and the search term is *bike* it will not echo me the link.
My main concern is the speed of the code.

```
<?php
$xml  = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');
$searchterm = "bike";
foreach ($xml->product as $product) {
if (strpos($product->name, $searchterm) !== false ) {
echo $product->link;
} }
?>
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You're looking for [`stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos)

If that isn't available to you, then just call [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/strtolower) on both strings first.

**EDIT**:

`stripos()` won't work if you want to find a substring with diacritical sign.

For example:

`stripos("Leży Jerzy na wieży i nie wierzy, że na wieży leży dużo JEŻY","jeży");` returns `false`, but it should return `int(68)`.

Comment: No, but it is slightly faster than using `strtolower()` first; on average, it (`stripos`) seems to take about 2.5 times longer (than `strpos`).  Then again, you can still do it (`stripos`) a million times per second, so I wouldn't worry that much about it -- premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: In theory, no solution can be, because there are more comparisons to be made. But here is some data: http://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm

Comment: It's true, and my figures are based on searching short strings (the million times a second comment); obviously, the longer the string, the longer it takes, and even longer for stripos.  However, in this question it seems like the strings will generally be short.

Comment: For example, if I increase the size of my search string by an order of magnitude, stripos goes from taking 0.2 seconds for 200,000 searches to taking 0.9 seconds; strpos, however, goes from 0.08 to 0.11

Comment: So its not a difference, as you said premature optimization. Is stripos faster than preg_match right?

Answer (score 14):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

stripos() is not case-sensitive.

Comment: Dereleased's comment didn't show up before I hit enter. Post ninja'd!

Comment: I blame the internet pixies, blocking the tubes with stale server-dust.

Answer (score 3):

**'i'** in **stripos()** means case insensitive

```
if(stripos($product->name, $searchterm) !== false){ //'i' case insensitive
        echo "Match = ".$product->link."<br />;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

make both name & $searchterm lowercase prior to $strpos.

```
$haystack = strtolower($product->name);
$needle = strtolower($searchterm);

if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false){  
    echo "Match = ".$product->link."<br />;
}
```