# Using strrpos() with PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make strpos non case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795383/how-to-make-strpos-non-case-sensitive)

I am testing to see if a string contains the text "People Who Like". Well, the code works great! Except it is case-sensitive. What can I do to prevent this?

If the string is "people who like to run" it returns false
If the string is "People who like to run" it returns true

I want it to not be case sensitive.

Code:

```
<?php

$string = "People who like to run";

if (strrpos($string, 'People who like') === false) {
    echo "False";
}
else {
    echo "True";
}
```

Answer (score 12):

See [`strripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php), the case insensitive-version of `strrpos`.

Answer (score 9):

use [strripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strripos.php) instead

OR

use strtolower on the string before testing it

```
$string = "People who like to run";

if (strrpos(strtolower($string), strtolower('People who like')) === false) {
    echo "False";
}
else {
    echo "True";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use strripos for case-insensitive match