# How to Check if the String is present in another String in any format?

Tags: php

I want to check if the string is present in another string

even if the string is in this format:
**are,
ARE,
Are,
aRe,
arE**

```
$str = "how aRe you doing";
if (strpos($str,'are') !== false) 
{
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make strpos case insensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795383/how-to-make-strpos-case-insensitive)

Comment: @Rizier123 Thanks!, i had to ask this question because i was unsuccessful in searching the solution on the web. maybe due to lack of keywords in my mind.

Comment: FYI: If you didn't knew it already you can also search stuff on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q= Also just use keywords if you search stuff e.g. `php strpos case insensitive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stripos()` instead of `strpos()`.

> int stripos ( string $main_string , string $substring [, int $offset = 0 ] )

Answer (score 1):

You can use strpos function with strtolower function

```
$str = "how are you doing";
$ndl = 'ArE';
if (strpos(strtolower($str),strtolower($ndl))) {
    echo "true";
}else{
    echo "false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "how aRe you doing";
if (strpos(strtolower($str),'are') !== false) 
{
    echo 'true';
}
```