# How to use PHP strpos not case sensitive?

Tags: php, case-sensitive, strpos

I have made a php script that searches a whole directory with text files in it, everything works fine, except that it is case sensitive. How would i search without it being case sensitive? Here's the code i have so far:

```
<?php
    $query = $_POST['search'];
    if ($handle = opendir('posts')) {
        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

                echo "<p>$entry ";
                $file = file_get_contents('posts/'.$entry, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
                $check_str = strpos($file,$query);

                if ($check_str == 0) {
                    print "not found</p>";
                } else {
                    print "found</p>";
                }

            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
?>
```

Comment: stripos http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php appropriately enough

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6795383/how-to-make-strpos-case-insensitive

Comment: I didn't even see that question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah, `stripos()` is what you're looking for. Here's [the manual page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) , :